# Click on body does not close pop up window selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to perform a body click on a webpage.
When I load a webpage there is a pop up that is displayed. I can close that pop up by clicking anywhere on the screen. This pop up does not have a standardised class name or id (keeps changing) So I want to simulate a button click on the body to close it.

I have tried

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').click()

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').click()
```

I get no error but the pop up is not closed

Then I tried to click on a random background element but it gave me an error when I tried

```
driver.find_element_class_name('abc').click()

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted
```

Is there any way to click on the body or other html tags to close it?

```
<div tabindex="-1" aria-modal="true" role="alertdialog" class="ca ew bz bx by c0 sb cr fs cw ap st t6 t7 sv sq i9 sw sx sy">
<div data-baseweb="block" class="qv c4 db c3">
<div data-baseweb="block" class="aq ar fq fr">A message </div>
<div data-baseweb="block" class="f5 aq e5 d8 at ao"><p data-baseweb="typo-paragraphlarge" class="fo aq e5 d8 at au dg">Spend $50 </p></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Is there a HTML for that pop up ? If URL is public can you share with us ?

Comment: Ive edited the code to provide the pop up code, url isnt public as of now

Comment: Please use @ to mention someone. I have created a HTML file with your shared HTML content still I don't see a close button.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dom element for that popup and just provide a click on that after a small wait of about 2-3 seconds.  It should work.

Note : Here you have used, **driver.find_element_name**, but it should be dom element like an id, a class, or some other attribute pertaining to that dom element.

```
driver.find_element_name('abc').click()

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted
```

Comment: dom element of the popup? As in one of the div of the popup? Clicking on the popup  isnt closing it, it needs to be clicked anywhere on the screen other than the popup to close it.

Comment: Okay. So clicking on the pop doesn't seem to close it. can we do a refresh in the page ? Maybe then the popup doesn't come.

Comment: Also it was a typo i was using element by class to click somewhere else

Comment: ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Arrays.asList("disable-popup-blocking"));
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

**Try this where you are setting / instantiating your chromedriver**

Answer (score 0):

It's just the popups take some time to display by that time your

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').click()
```

has been performed..

try giving some sleep before you perform `body.click()`

here is one example, but it's in java

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://bharathish-diggavi.github.io/Selenium-Practice/popup.html");
driver.findElement(By.id("popupButton")).click();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).click();;
```

Code doesn't work without sleep.

Comment: how did you get `https://bharathish-diggavi.github.io/Selenium-Practice/popup.html` ? I don't see this in OP

Comment: That page I just hosted for explanation

Comment: You don't get it. Different pages will have different ways to handle popup. moreover it's not python what you written above.

Answer (score 0):

You can not click on `body` or some background element with `Selenium` while those elements are actually covered by other elements since `Selenium` emulates user's `UI` actions.
So if you are attempting clicking on the below element the upper element is actually receipts that click. This is what literally `element click intercepted` error means.
In this case you can use a `JavaScript` click.
So, to click the `body` with `JS` try something like this:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementByTagName('body').click()")
```